# Best tracking algorithm for multiple colored objects (billiard balls)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Let me quickly explain what I have: I have written a custom detector that finds the regions in an image of billiard balls. I did this in using the HSV colorspace and for most ball's I could get away with only thresholding the Hue channel. However for orange (#5) and brown (#7) one must take the saturation into account which adds another dimension to the problem.

From my research it seems like my best route would be to do some manner of mean-shift tracking but everything I've come across has described mean-shift in which only one channel is used (the hue channel).

Can anyone please explain or offer a link explaing how I can adapt mean-shift to work using hue and saturation?

Or can you tell me if you think a different tracking algorithm may be better suited to this problem?

Comment: Could you create a channel representative of a single distance metric and then mean shift on that? For instance, if you're looking for brown, create an image that's `sqrt(huedistance^2 + saturationdistance^2)`. Then the mean shift will locate your maximum again.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting idea. Creating a new image every frame makes me a little weary about performance though because this is running on the iphone. But if it produces good results I could probably convert it into a shader.

Comment: Would you agree though that mean-shift is a good route to go down for this type of scenerio? Compared to something like surf/sift, optical flow, etc.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to do. Optical flow is only meaningful if things are moving. If you're trying to find billiard balls in a static image, optical flow won't help you. Likewise, billiard balls are basically coloured spheres -- they don't have a lot of identifiable features (except maybe the numbers if they're showing). With that in mind, SIFT/SURF features probably won't get you very far.

Comment: Well the idea is that someone would be videoing a table while walking around it, so essentially the balls would be moving. My detector gives me the ball blob's from an img which I could use as keypoints in Optical flow. Do you think that would be a better route to take? From what I've read it seems Optical flow is easier to implement in opencv than mean-shift at least.

Comment: It is not clear from the question whether you are trying to find the balls in a single image or track them in a video. Meanshift works well in multidimensional spaces, but I am not sure what are you tring to achieve

Comment: I have written my own detector that works well for a single image but becomes unstable when used for tracking. From the meager research I've done so far on Mean-Shift I was planning on using my detector on the initial frame (and again when objects move offscreen?). Then use histograms of the H & S channels from the segments my detector found as the input to Mean-Shift. It may be a stretch but I wanted to also experiment with using the same strategy with my felt detector and have it track the table corners.

Answer (score 0):

In theory mean shift works well regardless of the dimensionality (in very high dimensions sparseness is a bit of an issues, but there are works that address that problem)

If you are trying to use an off the self mean shift tracker that only takes a single channel input, you can create your own problem specific color channel. You need a single channel that maximizes the difference between the different colored billiard balls.

The easiest way of doing that will be to take the mean colors of all 15 balls and, put them in a `15x3` matrix and decompose it with `SVD` (subtract the mean first) so you'll get the axis of maximal variance. This will give you the best linear transformation from RGB to a new one dimensional color space that maximizes difference between the billiard balls colors. (If it isn't good enough you can do better with local mapping, but might not be necessary)

Comment: When you say "subtract the mean first" about decomposing the SVD how is that accomplished with openCV? Not being familiar with it, its hard to tell from the docs (http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1SVD.html#a52086af6fd6702e17073b8693de6d6b0).

Comment: Also I've had difficulty being able to "maximizes difference between colors" with the orange/brown and green/blue color groups. A standard mean operation won't give a "visually" proportional distribution of the colors. The opencv docs don't detail cv::SVD too much so I'm wondering if this does anything beyond a standard mean?